# trig substitution $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}dx$

Tags: integration

$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}dx$

I let $x = 2 \sec(\theta)$, then $dx = 2\sec(\theta) \tan(\theta) d \theta$

$$\int \frac{2\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)}{2\sec(\theta)2\tan(\theta)}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\theta + C = \frac{1}{2} \sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + C$$

Therefore the answer would be this after simplification?:

All I did is:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{2}^{3} f(x)dx + \int_{3}^{\infty} f(x)dx$$

$$\lim_{A\to2^+} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sec^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\bigg|_{A}^{3} + \lim_{B\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sec^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\bigg|_{3}^{B}$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} (sec^{-1} (\frac{3}{2}) - 0)+ \frac{1}{2}(\pi/2 - sec^{-1}(3/2)) = \pi/4$$ Converges.

Is this right?

Comment: You haven't completed your answer, so it can't be right.

Comment: Also, you forgot to change the limits.

Comment: Okay i simplified it.

Comment: You still need to change your limits. $\theta$ no longer goes from $2$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @DHMO he's changed back to $x$, surely?

Comment: Oh, in that case it surely isn't infinity. $\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac22\right) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry i messed up mentally doing it. Changed

Comment: What do you mean by changing the limit? I first just integrated it, then put in the limits.

Comment: @Tinler you seem to be a factor of $-1$ off.

Comment: I don't get it. I look at it couple times my trig sub is correct I think because $u^2 - a^2$ is a $x = usec(\theta)$ substitution. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, your last line is off by a sign all the way through: it should be $(f(3) - f(A)) + (f(B) - f(3))$. I also don't see why you want to break it up at 3: the lower limit of the integral does not cause any problems at all.

Comment: Yeah i messed up on FTOC forgot its top part - bottom part, thx. 2 does cause a problem. $2^2 - 4 = 0, 1/0 $

Comment: So what? The integrand may misbehave there, but the integrated form does not.

Comment: But it does. $sec^{-1} (x)$ is $1/(cos^{-1} (x))$, which means $1/cos^{-1}(1) = 1/0$. Oh wait nvm u could be right. Yeah nvm

Comment: @Tinler Are you satisfied with the answer i gave.

Comment: I'm content with just figuring what I did wrong. As for your answer I did upvote you  but my textbook doesn't use hyperbolic trig nor have I ever so. I do get what you did though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POINT OUTS: You did not change limits. and it looks weird.
But to solve via your method you just need to compute:
$$\int^\frac{\pi}{2} _0 \frac{d \theta}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
My method: let $x=\frac{1}{t}$
$$\int^0_\frac{1}{2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-4t^2}}$$
Which is equivalent to $$\int^0 _\frac{1}{2} 
\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-(2t)^2}}$$

Now i hope you know $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+C$$

Comment: Is my answer not correct?

Comment: It is. @Tinler Please see the edit.

Comment: Why doesn't $u^2 - a^2$ go for $x = usec(\theta)$ ? I only know of 3 from my textbook which are sec, tan, sin. And sin is $a^2 - u^2$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't seem to get your question. What are you pointing at? @Tinler

Comment: What is wrong with my solution? I'm not saying it isn't wrong since wolfram give $\pi/4$ as well but I don't know what step I did wrong.

Comment: The only thing that irks me in your solution is that convergence bit. Why to complicate the situation? Simply put $\infty$ and 2 and get your answer. @Tinler

Comment: It is wrong though by $(-1)$, but I cant seem to pinpoint why.

Comment: all you need to do after getting $\frac {1}{2} \int \sec ^{-1} (\frac{\theta}{2}) $ is this : $\frac{1}{2}(\sec ^{-1} (0) - \sec ^{-1} (1) )$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If trigonometric substitution is not mandatory, choose $$\sqrt{x^2-4}=y$$

$\frac1{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\frac x{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}$

Now change the limits accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

**hint**
the integral is convergent since

$$f (x)\sim \frac {1}{x^2}\;\;(x\to\infty) $$

$$f(x)\sim \frac{1}{4\sqrt{x-2}}\;\;(x\to2^+)$$

to find its value,
put $$x=2\cosh (t) =2\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}.$$
 $x=2\implies t=0$

$x\to \infty\implies t \to \infty $.

on the other hand,

$$dx=2\sinh (t) $$
and
$$\cosh^2 (t)-\sinh^2 (t)=1.$$

thus

$$x\sqrt {x^2-4}=4\cosh(t)\sinh(t). $$

the integral becomes

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{e^t+e^{-t}} $$ 
$$\color {green}{\boxed {=[\arctan(e^t)]_0^\infty=\frac {\pi}{4}}}$$